# What breed of cat is this?

Tags: cats, identification

[image: Tucker, my 4-year-old cat]

I may have a couple guesses, but I'm pretty sure I'm wrong.

Comment: "What breed is this?" questions are off-topic. "Short-hair tabby" is about all you can say. Anyway, he looks just like my mog when I haven't given him his favourite treat.

Comment: first cat breed questions is off topic,second it is a natural cat no type of breed it is how nature makes them without intervention from people and it is perfect.

Comment: I believe the classification is "Domestic Shorthair Tabby"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Domestic Shorthair Tabby

Thanks to @Stig Tore. But that says very [little if any thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domestic_short-haired_cat) about your cat. Other than that it's a cat: domesticated from wild cats with a certain pattern to their fur.

Now, if you could take it to a [cat show judge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_show), you might get a better estimate. They do know their stuff better then some internet stanger(s).

In the end, if you **don't know the breed,** that is, you don't have the papers from the parents, **it's not from a recognised breed**. But papers or not, that has no influence on the suitability for being a good pet.